# Using a button to run a SQL query with flask

Tags: python, flask

On userpage page I have an "add" button which is supposed to send an add request to another user. The flask code for the button uses the friend_request table which needs the user id of the request sender which is stored in session[user_ID] and the receiver whose ID is stored in data.uid (in HTML) which originates from "data" on userpage() route, 
Flask code for users page:

```
@app.route('/user/<user_id>')
def userpage(user_id):
    user_id = int(user_id)
    c = sq.connection.cursor()

    try:
        result = c.execute('SELECT * FROM users WHERE uid = %s ',(user_id))
    except:
        print('Error','info')
    data = c.fetchall()

    return render_template('user/profpage.html', data=data[0])
```

Userpage HTML:

```
<h1>Name here</h1>
<p> Description, of a really cool person</p>

<p> {{ data.fname }}</p>
<p> {{ data.lname }}</p>
<p> {{ data.email }}</p>
{% if session['user_ID'] != data.uid %}
    <a href="/user/add/{{ data.uid }}" class="btn btn-primary" name="Add">Add</a>
{% endif %}
```

Flask code for Add button:

```
@app.route('/user/add/<user_id>')
def useradd(user_id):
    user_id = int(user_id)
    c = sq.connection.cursor()
    try:
        result = c.execute('INSERT INTO friend_requests(req_by,req_to) VALUES (%s,%s) ',(session['user_ID'],user_id))
        sq.connection.commit()
    except:
        print('Error','info')

    return redirect(url_for('userpage'))
```

when I try to implement this it enters the information into the datebase table however, I get the following error "werkzeug.routing.BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'userpage'. Did you forget to specify values ['user_id']?"

Comment: `url_for('userpage', user_id=session['user_ID'])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code

```
return redirect(url_for('userpage'))
```

try to use `route('/user/')` to build URL but you have only `route('/user/<user_id>')` which expects `user_id` as parameter - so you have to add this `user_id` in `url_for`

```
url_for('userpage', user_id=user_id)
```

or

```
url_for('userpage', user_id=session['user_ID'])
```

Comment: Thanks it worked out, Also, I'm fairly new to flask, is there a better way to create a button like this?

Comment: you can use `url_for` in HTML too. `href="{{ url_for('useradd', user_id=data.uid) }}"`. When you decide to change url in `@app.route(...)` then you don't have to change it in HTML. But I prefer `href="/user/add/{{ data.uid }}"` because I can see this url in HTML and don't have to search it in code.